# Unable to open new window on successful login Post - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am very new to Swift.  I am trying to build an app where -

I have a login screen and once the user types in the correct username and password, the user is redirected to a new window. I have successfully managed to do the HTTP post requests but after that I am unable open a new window on successful login.

```
@IBAction func signinTapped(sender: UIButton) {
   let parameters = "{\"email\": \""+txtUserName.text+"\", \"password\": \""+txtPassword.text+"\"}" ;//as Dictionary<String, String>

    //create the url with NSURL      
    let url = NSURL(string: "https://myurl") //change the url

    //create the session object      
    var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)     
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST" //set http method as POST

    var err: NSError?  
    request.HTTPBody = parameters.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true);//NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(parameters, options: nil, error: &err) // pass dictionary to nsdata object and set it as request body        
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")       
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    //create dataTask using the session object to send data to the server     
    var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in     
        println("Response: \(response)")           
        let strData = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)          
        println(strData)           
        var err: NSError?

        var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableLeaves, error: &err) as? NSDictionary

        // Did the JSONObjectWithData constructor return an error? If so, log the error to the console

        if(err != nil) {          
            println(err!.localizedDescription)              
            let jsonStr = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)               
            println("Error could not parse JSON: '\(jsonStr)'")                
        }                
        else {             
            // The JSONObjectWithData constructor didn't return an error. But, we should still

            // check and make sure that json has a value using optional binding.       
            if let parseJSON = json {                 
                // Okay, the parsedJSON is here, let's get the value for 'success' out of it

                var success = parseJSON["success"] as? Int      
                println("Succes: \(success)")                  
            }

            else {                  
                // Woa, okay the json object was nil, something went worng. Maybe the server isn't running?              
                let jsonStr = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)                    
                println("Error could not parse JSON: \(jsonStr)")                   
            }

        }

    })
```

Can some one please give me an example. any help much appreciated.

Many thanks

This is the crash log as requested by @Dharmesh Kheni

```
    2015-06-20 16:53:44.028 Login[29072:191664] *** Assertion failure in -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3347.44/Keyboard/UIKeyboardTaskQueue.m:374
2015-06-20 16:53:44.033 Login[29072:191664] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished] may only be called from the main thread.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c932c65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010e49dbb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c932aca +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010cdcf98f -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 195
    4   UIKit                               0x000000010d929936 -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished] + 151
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010d3ca952 -[UIKeyboardImpl setDelegate:force:] + 473
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010d67560d -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) _reloadInputViewsForResponder:] + 1002
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010d67d994 -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) _preserveInputViewsWithId:animated:reset:] + 504
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010d30d531 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:modalSourceViewController:presentationController:animationController:interactionController:completion:] + 623
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010d30e7ae -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 3079
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010d310701 __62-[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:]_block_invoke + 132
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010d310625 -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 229
    12  Login                               0x000000010c70d420 _TFFC5Login7LoginVC12signinTappedFS0_FCSo8UIButtonT_U_FTGSQCSo6NSData_GSQCSo13NSURLResponse_GSQCSo7NSError__T_ + 3344
    13  Login                               0x000000010c70d723 _TTRXFo_oGSQCSo6NSData_oGSQCSo13NSURLResponse_oGSQCSo7NSError__dT__XFo_iTGSQS__GSQS0__GSQS1____iT__ + 51
    14  Login                               0x000000010c70abe1 _TPA__TTRXFo_oGSQCSo6NSData_oGSQCSo13NSURLResponse_oGSQCSo7NSError__dT__XFo_iTGSQS__GSQS0__GSQS1____iT__ + 81
    15  Login                               0x000000010c70d753 _TTRXFo_iTGSQCSo6NSData_GSQCSo13NSURLResponse_GSQCSo7NSError___iT__XFo_oGSQS__oGSQS0__oGSQS1___dT__ + 35
    16  Login                               0x000000010c70d7ba _TTRXFo_oGSQCSo6NSData_oGSQCSo13NSURLResponse_oGSQCSo7NSError__dT__XFdCb_dGSQS__dGSQS0__dGSQS1___dT__ + 90
    17  CFNetwork                           0x000000010f6a600b __49-[__NSCFLocalSessionTask _task_onqueue_didFinish]_block_invoke + 157
    18  Foundation                          0x000000010cdf357f __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 7
    19  Foundation                          0x000000010cd340b2 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 98
    20  Foundation                          0x000000010cd16774 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 645
    21  Foundation                          0x000000010cd16383 __NSOQSchedule_f + 184
    22  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010ebc1614 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    23  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010eba86a7 _dispatch_queue_drain + 2176
    24  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010eba7cc0 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 235
    25  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010ebab3b9 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1359
    26  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010ebacb17 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 111
    27  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010ef2e6cb _pthread_wqthread + 729
    28  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010ef2c4a1 start_wqthread + 13
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can initiate new view controller this way when user successfully log In:

```
if let parseJSON = json {
        // Okay, the parsedJSON is here, let's get the value for 'success' out of it

        var success = parseJSON["success"] as? Int
        println("Succes: \(success)")

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("YourViewControllerID") as! UIViewController
            self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

And don't forget to give an identifier to next view by clicking on your view controller in storyboard go to identity inspector set StoryBoard ID as shown in below Image:

[image]

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks @Dharmesh for your detailed prompt reply.I did as you mentioned but app crashed.  *** Assertion failure in -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3347.44/Keyboard/UIKeyboardTaskQueue.m:374
2015-06-20 16:28:25.797 Login[27119:180067] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished] may only be called from the main thread.'

Comment: @Dharnesh, I have added the crash report to the original question itself. All your help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81069/discussion-between-dharmesh-kheni-and-bably).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if(success == 1)
{
 let viewcontroller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Storyboard Id") as viewcontrollerName
 var navController:UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewcontroller)
 UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController = navController
}
```

Answer (score -1):

On successful login,

```
let vc = ViewController() //Your view controller to present 
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```